# (Blender 2.8) My Mesh is mess when i move my rig

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, pose-mode

please someone help me. im using Blender 2.8

Currently i'm doing rigging in my own model. i'm using **Automatic Weight** as a rigged parent from my model

The problem is, when i'm tried to move (rotate) my model's hand in pose mode. it's getting messed up

[image]

And the legs are as same as hand

[image]

i've been trying to reduce the **weight** down to 0 in weight painting. but the result was as bad as before
[image]

Could someone help me to solve this problem ? is there something that i missed ?

Thanks before

File :
[My Blender File][4]

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: yes, well done!

Comment: Do you find what did i missed with my rigging ?

Comment: you have to do weight painting ....since you are a beginner i would recommend to watch several rigging tutorials on yt - there are thousands of them out there.

Comment: Yeah, i did it in 3rd photo. But as you see it didn't solved the problem.. The model is still messed up, what i want to know which part did i missed

Comment: You accidentally painted his cheek when painting his arm. I recommend assigning vertices manually in edit mode to recreated empty groups, then using corrective smooth.

Comment: It works ! I remove all my vertices manually and assign and weight painting, then my model didn't messed up again. You're more informative than the ones who take my model for free with no better explanation. Thank you very much, sir  i have learn something too, hope you have a wonderful life